# What's Wrong With My Batch File

Tags: batch-file

Trying to create a batch file to make these tasks run faster.

Can someone please correct my errors or suggest a better way to write this script

Basically everytime I run it says "request timed out"

```
@echo off
color 0a
Title 

:Beginning 
set /p UserInput = What Would You Like To Start?
echo.

if %UserInput% == 1 goto :Windows Update
if not %UserInput% == "" goto :Exit
else goto :Exit

if %UserInput% == 2 goto :Group Policy Update
if not %UserInput% == "" goto :Exit
else goto :Exit

if %UserInput% == 5 goto :Favorites
if not %UserInput% == "" goto :Exit
else goto :Exit

if %UserInput% == 3 goto :Tools
if not %UserInput% == "" goto :Exit
else goto :Exit

 if %UserInput% == 4 goto :Printer
 if not %UserInput% == "" goto :Exit
 else goto :Exit

:Windows Update
start C:\Windows\system32\wuapp.exe
pause 
exit

:Group Policy Update 
start gpupdate.exe
pause
exit 

:Favorites 
move %userprofile%\favorites\*.* G:\
pause 
exit

:Tools
start \\NoneOFyourBusiness
pause 
exit

:Printer
start iexplore.exe http://www.Google.com
pause
exit

:Exit
set /p beginning == Return To The Start?
echo.
echo Y=Yes or N=No
if %beginning% == "Y" goto :Beginning 
if not %beginning% == "N" goto :Exit 2

:Exit 2
pause 
exit**'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
color 0a
Title Testing

REM Since exit is a keyword - changed to leave

:Begining 
echo choose an option
choice /c 12345

rem set /p UserInput = What Would You Like To Start?
echo.

if %errorlevel% == 1 goto WindowsUpdate

if %errorlevel% == 2 goto GroupPolicyUpdate

if %errorlevel% EQU 5 goto Favorites

if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto Tools

if %errorlevel% EQU 4 goto Printer

:WindowsUpdate
start C:\Windows\system32\wuapp.exe
pause 
goto leave

:GroupPolicyUpdate 
start gpupdate.exe
pause
goto leave 

:Favorites 
move %userprofile%\favorites\*.* G:\
pause 
goto leave

:Tools
start \\NoneOFyourBusiness
pause 
goto leave

:Printer
start iexplore.exe http://www.Google.com
pause
goto leave

:leave
echo leave the script?
choice /c YN
if %errorlevel% NEQ 1 goto Begining
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 exit
```

Comment: If I helped you..  Can you please rate/Mark my answer as useful/Helpful?

Comment: Absolutely Sir. I'm new, so I'm not too familiar with everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
set /p UserInput = What Would You Like To Start?
```

Will apply the input string to a variable named UserInput<kbd>Space</kbd>

Batch is sensitive to spaces on both sides of the <kbd>=</kbd> in a `set` (but not a `set /a`)

```
if not %UserInput% == "" goto :Exit
```

Because you have no control over the use's input, that may contain spaces and other character to which batch is sensitive.

use

```
if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto :Exit
```

Note that the two strings must be **exactly** equal. `IF /i ...` will make the test case-insensitive.

Note also that responding simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a `set /p` will leave the variable unchanged, it will not "set" it to an empty string. If you want that, use

```
set "var="
set /p var=
```

Also, to detect whether `var` has been set, use

```
if defined var


if "%UserInput%"=="1" goto :Windows Update
```

This is a fail-to-fail scenario. The real command executed will be

```
if "%UserInput%"=="1" goto Windows
```

The remaining text after the space-separator is documentation.

Not a good idea IMHO to use the colon in a `goto`. It works, but there is a difference with a `CALL` statement. `CALL :something` will execute an **internal** subroutine (ie subroutine in this batch file) named `something`, whereas `CALL something` without the colon will call an **external** executable. By analogy, `GOTO` should also not be used with a colon. The one exception is the documented special condition, `GOTO :EOF` where the colon **is** required. `GOTO :EOF` means 'go to the end of the physical batch file.`The label`EOF`need not (indeed **should** not) be included in the batch.`CMD` knows where it has to go...

So - fix those and it should work a lot better. Not sure what the error response you have is, but I'd suggest it's some utility you'd not expected to run getting tired of waiting for input.

Comment: Thanks your advice helped allot but my batch still won't work.

Comment: +1, I like everything you say, except I disagree regarding colons with the GOTO statement. However, that is all a matter of opinion. I agree the documentation never states that you can use the colon, but it most certainly works; I've never seen any negative impact. And your logic regarding internal vs external escapes me. CALL with colons calls an internal label with colons, so  it makes sense that GOTO with colons would also branch to an internal label with colons. I've never seen documentation stating you can add remarks after a label, but it works and is useful. Both seem valid to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **     @echo off
   color 0a
   Title 
  :Beginning 
   set UserInput=Error
   set /p UserInput=What Would You Like To Start?
   echo.
   if "%UserInput%"=="WU" goto Windows Update
   if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto Exit
   if "%UserInput%"=="GPU" goto Group Policy Update
   if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto Exit
   if "%UserInput%"=="Fav" goto Favorites
   if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto Exit
   if "%UserInput%"=="T" goto Tools
   if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto Exit
   if "%UserInput%"=="P" goto Printer
   if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto Exit
  :Windows Update
   start C:\Windows\system32\wuapp.exe
   goto exit
  :Group Policy Update 
   start gpupdate.exe
   goto exit 
   :Favorites 
   move %userprofile%\favorites\*.* G:\
   goto exit
  :Tools
   start \\T
   goto exit
  :Printer
   start iexplore.exe http://Google.com/
  :Exit
   set Beginning==Error
   set /p Beginning==Return To The Start?
   echo.
   echo y=Yes or n=No
   if "%Beginning%"=="y" call :Beginning 
   if not "%Beginning%"=="n" goto Exit 2
  :Exit 2
   pause 
   exit**
```

Comment: Couple thoughts here..  Where you have `if "%UserInput%"=="WU" goto Windows Update` you may do better to do: `if "%UserInput%"=="WU" goto WindowsUpdate` (remove space)..  Also, this may be better for the comparators:  `if "%UserInput%" EQU "WU" goto WindowsUpdate`..  HTH.

Comment: With Labels no spaces are allowed.  `goto Group Policy Update` will jump to Label `Group` and ignore `Policy Update`. Same with `goto exit 2` (it **seems** to work ok in this special code because of the way, batch searches for labels)

Comment: You should replace the last `if not "%UserInput%"=="" goto Exit` and change the last one to `goto Exit` only.